# How to start over again a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON file which stores an array of picture URLs. I want to rotate through these links, changing the background of a `div` every 4 seconds.

I'm having no trouble accessing the JSON file or changing the background of the div. However, I can't seem to figure out how to restart at the beginning of the array after every picture has been shown.

How should I approach this problem?

```
$.getJSON(json, function (data) {
    var arr = $.map(data, function (el) { return el; })
      , i = 0;

    var changeObj = function() {
        i++;
        var url = 'url("' + arr[i].url + '")';
        $this.css({
            backgroundImage: url
        });
    };

    setInterval(changeObj, 4000);           
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://davidedc.altervista.org/my-brand/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your have already parsed your `JSON` into an array of URLs called `myPictureArray` and you have written a function called `swapInNewPicture`, which takes a URL of an image as its argument. (I'm not going to write these functions for you.)

```
var rotatePictures = function (arr) {
    var length = arr.length
      , i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        i = (i + 1) % length;
        swapInNewPicture(arr[i]);
    }, 4000)
}
```

Now, all you have to do is call `rotatePictures(myPictureArray)` after you finish parsing your `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operation so it wraps around when it reaches the end of the array. Replace:

```
i++;
```

with:

```
i = (i + 1) % arr.length;
```

This is basically equivalent to:

```
i++;
if (i == arr.length) {
    i = 0;
}
```

BTW, you can simplify the `setInterval` call to:

```
setInterval(changeObj, 4000);
```